# Android 7.x (API24) WEEK_OF_MONTH Calendar Bug?

Tags: android, calendar, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

We've got some strange behavior in Android 7 (API 24/25) using `Calendar`.

Given this fairly simple code:

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"), Locale.GERMANY);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

for (int month = Calendar.JANUARY; month <= Calendar.DECEMBER; month++) {
    Calendar start = ((Calendar) cal.clone());
    start.set(2017, month, 1);

    Calendar end = ((Calendar) start.clone());
    end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Log.d("CAL", "\n    Date Start: " + month_date.format(start.getTime()) + " " +
        " WEEK_OF_MONTH: " + start.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
    );
    Log.d("CAL", "\n    Date End: " + month_date.format(end.getTime()) +
        " WEEK_OF_MONTH: " + end.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
       );
}
```

Running on Android 4.0x, 5.x and 6.x showing the right value for `WEEK_OF_MONTH`:

```
 Date Start: 01.01.2016  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.01.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
 Date Start: 01.02.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 28.02.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.03.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.03.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.04.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.04.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.05.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.05.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.06.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.06.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.07.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.07.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
 Date Start: 01.08.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.08.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.09.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.09.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.10.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.10.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
 Date Start: 01.11.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.11.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.12.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.12.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
```

Running on Android 7.x broken `WEEK_OF_MONTH`:

```
 Date Start: 01.01.2016  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 31.01.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.02.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 28.02.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.03.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.03.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.04.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 30.04.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 4
 Date Start: 01.05.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.05.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.06.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.06.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.07.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 31.07.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.08.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 31.08.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.09.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 30.09.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 4
 Date Start: 01.10.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 31.10.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.11.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
 Date End: 30.11.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
 Date Start: 01.12.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0
 Date End: 31.12.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 4
```

We couldn't find any documented changes for `Calendar` in API 24.

Any clue how to solve this issue?

We already implemented our own method for `WEEK_OF_MONTH` returning the same values as Android 6.x but by the looks of it `set(WEEK_OF_MONTH)` is also broken.
Rewriting the code using Joda is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` method to [change how the weeks are counted](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_and_year):

```java
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"), Locale.GERMANY);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);
```

This will produce the correct values for **week of month**.

---

You told that rewriting the code with Joda-Time is not an option, but what about another API?

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes, together with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

<sup>*BTW, Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.*</sup>

The classes below are under the `org.threeten.bp` package. The code will be like this:

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import org.threeten.bp.DayOfWeek;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.Month;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.WeekFields;

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // day and month
    .appendPattern("dd.MM.")
    // week based year (equivalent to YYYY in SimpleDateFormat)
    .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear())
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter(Locale.GERMANY);

// week starting at monday, consider week=1 even if it has 1 day (default is 4)
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 1);
for (Month month : Month.values()) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, month, 1);
    LocalDate end = start.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());

    System.out.println("Date Start: " + fmt.format(start) + " " + " WEEK_OF_MONTH: " + start.get(wf.weekOfMonth()));
    System.out.println("Date End: " + fmt.format(end) + " WEEK_OF_MONTH: " + end.get(wf.weekOfMonth()));
}
```

The output will be:

```java
Date Start: 01.01.2016  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.01.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
Date Start: 01.02.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 28.02.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.03.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.03.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.04.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 30.04.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.05.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.05.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.06.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 30.06.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.07.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.07.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
Date Start: 01.08.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.08.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.09.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 30.09.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.10.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.10.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 6
Date Start: 01.11.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 30.11.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
Date Start: 01.12.2017  WEEK_OF_MONTH: 1
Date End: 31.12.2017 WEEK_OF_MONTH: 5
```